# How to make the label that wraps a button clickable too in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, label

Having the following components:

```
  <CheckboxGroupLabel htmlFor={option.label}>
    <FormCheckbox
      onClick={() => onChange}
      key={option.label}
      defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
      {...rest}
    />
    {option.value}
  </CheckboxGroupLabel>
```

Their styled components are:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as Checkbox from '@radix-ui/react-checkbox';

export const CheckboxGroupLabel = styled.label`
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
`;

export const StyledCheckboxRoot = styled(Checkbox.Root)`
  button {
    all: unset;
  }
`;
```

So the checkbox is inside label but only checkbox is clickable, I would like to make the whole label clickable.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just moving `onClick` into `CheckboxGroupLabel`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/label-onclick-3ebkbi

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as Checkbox from "@radix-ui/react-checkbox";
import { CheckIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const onLabelClick = () => {
    console.log("clicked label");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label onClick={onLabelClick} htmlFor="mycheckbox">
        <Checkbox.Root className="checkbox" defaultChecked id="mycheckbox">
          <Checkbox.Indicator className="indicator">
            <CheckIcon />
          </Checkbox.Indicator>
          My checkbox label
        </Checkbox.Root>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried but didn't work

Comment: It works. See updated live demo. The issue is that your code doesn't provide a reproducible working example. I've reduced it to a working example based off the Radix docs. Your question is a straightforward one. You only ask how to make the label clickable. But is there something you need to do on click? Is there more to your question? Why won't this solution work exactly?